# Getting class does not exist error when running database seeder

Tags: laravel

I am creating a seeder in laravel 6.1 but I keep getting this error

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException  : Target class [AdminsTableSeeder] does not exist.

I tried running composer dump-autoload and composer dumpautoload, it doesn't work for me.

here is my AdminsTableSeeder.php

```
use App\Models\Admin;
use Faker\Factory as Faker;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class AdminsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $faker = Faker::create();

    Admin::create([
        'name'      =>  $faker->name,
        'email'     =>  'admin@admin.com',
        'password'  =>  bcrypt('password'),
    ]);
}
}
```

and here is my DatabaseSeeder.php
<?php

```
 use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

 class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
 {
/**
 * Seed the application's database.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
   $this->call(AdminsTableSeeder::class);
}
}
```

Comment: tried but it isnt working.

Comment: @Muhammad it's not neccesary if you don't put the seeder in a subdirectory (in fact, because you will change the seeder namespace)

Answer (score 24):

Make sure your `AdminsTableSeeder.php` file is in the same directory where you have your `DatabaseSeeder.php` file.

Run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

then try

```
php artisan db:seed
```

Optional.

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
     /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run(){
        $this->call('AdminsTableSeeder');
    }
}
```

try with  `$this->call('AdminsTableSeeder');` like this.

Comment: tried this but it isn't working, any other way of resolving it, been stuck on it for half the day now.

Comment: yay! I resolved it . It was because I was missing the <?php at the top of the AdminsTableSeeder file.

Answer (score 13):

*In your case, move all seeder files from previous `database/seeds` directory to `database/seeders` folder & then run `composer dump-autoload`.*

---

### Remember, from **`laravel 8`** seeders and factories are namespaced

To accommodate for these changes,

[1] - Add `Database\Seeders` namespace to your seeder classes.

```
 namespace Database\Seeders;
```

[2] - Move all seeder files to `database/seeders` folder.

[3] - If you import any seeders classes in `DatabaseSeeder` file then remove all of them. (*simply remove all lines that started with *`use Database\Seeders\...`* from DatabaseSeeder.php*)

[4] - Finally run `dump-autoload`.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

---

***You can now try a fresh migration with seed,***

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

Comment: the command "composer dump-autoload" solve my problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For my case(I use Laravel 8), I solved my problem by modifying the RouteServiceProvider.php file in App/Providers/ path. I uncommented code on line 29.

```
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

It worked for me.

Comment: This is nothing to do with database seeding.

Answer (score 2):

run

> composer dump-autoload

then try

> php artisan db:seed

Comment: These steps were already mentioned in previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 8:

I have the same issue and I found a solution in Laravel doc and it's worked for me.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#seeder-factory-namespaces

Update Composer:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
}
```

Run:

```
composer dumpautoload

php artisan db:seed --force
```

Comment: These steps were already mentioned in previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning my case, I used the latest  Laravel 8 which is the latest version, I solved my problem by changing the RouteServiceProvider.php file in App/Providers/ path by uncommenting the code on line 29.

protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

Comment: The question is about an error while seeding the database, the route service provider has no bearing on that whatsoever.

Answer (score -1):

For Laravel ^7.0

If your using Laravel Eloquent

Example:

```
<?php

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $users = [
            [
                'id'             => 1,
                'name'           => 'Admin',
                'email'          => 'admin@admin.com',
                'password'       => bcrypt('password'),
                'remember_token' => null,
            ],
        ];

        User::insert($users);
    }
}
```

If your using Laravel Query Builder

Example:

```
<?php

//Do not use -> namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name'           => 'Admin',
            'email'          => 'admin@admin.com',
            'password'       => bcrypt('password'),
            'remember_token' => null,
        ]);
    }
}
```

In your DatabaseSeeder.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call([
            UsersTableSeeder::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem is this answer solving? I don't see a relationship to the error or code in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like the controller name is case-sensitive in Laravel 8. So my suggestion is to double-check the controller name.

For instance:
in web.php avoid calling

`UserAPIController`

as

`UserApiController`

(**API** as **api**)

It may fix this error.

Comment: What do controller names have to do with a database seeding error?

Answer (score -1):

In your DatabaseSeeder.php, you can add the nameSpace for AdminsTableSeeder like -

```
use App\Models\Admin\AdminsTableSeeder;
```

Comment: That's not a valid namespace for a seeder, and seeders in Laravel 6.1 are not namespaced at all anyway.