# Seeding: UsersTableSeeder In Container.php line 729: Class UsersTableSeeder does not exist

Tags: laravel

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\User;

class UsersTableSeeder Extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
        {
            $user = User::create(array(
                'email' => $faker->email,
                'username' => $faker->unique()->userName,
                'password' => $faker->word,
                'remember_token' => str_random(50)
            ));
        }

    }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... can you run `composer dump` and see if anything changes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException : Target class \[AdminsTableSeeder\] does not exist. error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58354272/getting-illuminate-contracts-container-bindingresolutionexception-target-class)

Comment: run composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 2):

as `UsersTableSeeder` is not found u need to dump your autoload then this class will load in laravel

run `composer dump-autoload` it will work

Answer (score -2):

Provider: Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class, Aliases: 'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class, In config/app.php

then

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash; at the UsersTableSeeder.php

this works for me