# class LaratrustSeeder does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, web, back

I tried to clear the cache and config and do vendor and dumpload everything but keeps telling me

> the class Laratrust does not exist

I am using laravel 8
any solutions??

this is LaratrustSeeder.php

```
    <?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class LaratrustSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->truncateLaratrustTables();

        $config = config('laratrust_seeder.roles_structure');
        $mapPermission = collect(config('laratrust_seeder.permissions_map'));

        foreach ($config as $key => $modules) {

            // Create a new role
            $role = \App\Models\Role::firstOrCreate([
                'name' => $key,
                'display_name' => ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $key)),
                'description' => ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $key))
            ]);
            $permissions = [];

            $this->command->info('Creating Role '. strtoupper($key));

            // Reading role permission modules
            foreach ($modules as $module => $value) {

                foreach (explode(',', $value) as $p => $perm) {

                    $permissionValue = $mapPermission->get($perm);

                    $permissions[] = \App\Models\Permission::firstOrCreate([
                        'name' => $module . '-' . $permissionValue,
                        'display_name' => ucfirst($permissionValue) . ' ' . ucfirst($module),
                        'description' => ucfirst($permissionValue) . ' ' . ucfirst($module),
                    ])->id;

                    $this->command->info('Creating Permission to '.$permissionValue.' for '. $module);
                }
            }

            // Attach all permissions to the role
            $role->permissions()->sync($permissions);

            if(Config::get('laratrust_seeder.create_users')) {
                $this->command->info("Creating '{$key}' user");
                // Create default user for each role
                $user = \App\Models\User::create([
                    'name' => ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $key)),
                    'email' => $key.'@app.com',
                    'password' => bcrypt('password')
                ]);
                $user->attachRole($role);
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * Truncates all the laratrust tables and the users table
     *
     * @return    void
     */
    public function truncateLaratrustTables()
    {
        $this->command->info('Truncating User, Role and Permission tables');
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        DB::table('permission_role')->truncate();
        DB::table('permission_user')->truncate();
        DB::table('role_user')->truncate();
        if(Config::get('laratrust_seeder.truncate_tables')) {
            \App\Models\Role::truncate();
            \App\Models\Permission::truncate();
        }
        if(Config::get('laratrust_seeder.truncate_tables') && Config::get('laratrust_seeder.create_users')) {
            \App\Models\User::truncate();
        }
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }
}



at config\app

added this to providers

            'Laratrust\LaratrustServiceProvider::class,'

and this to alias

        'Laratrust' => Laratrust\LaratrustFacade::class,
```

DatabaseSeeder.php file

```
        <?php
    
    namespace Database\Seeders;
    
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
    use LaratrustSeeder;
    
    class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
    {
        /**
         * Seed the application's database.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run()
        {
            // User::factory(10)->create();
            $this->call(LaratrustSeeder::class);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO .. rename `LatatrustSeeder.php` to `LaratrustSeeder.php`

Comment: stll telling me this error

i tried
composer dump-autoload
then
php artisan db:Seed

Comment: Please check, is your `LaratrustSeeder` class misses the namespace?

Comment: what is the error return?

Comment: yes no namespace

Comment: cann you check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58354385/9978078

Comment: @MEDObro can u put code where you are calling this or by cmd

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all make sure that *santigarcor/laratrust* is installed/listed in a **composer.json** file. if not, edit your composer.json file *"require": {*

[where to place santigarcor/laratrust in composer. json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbJ3X.png)

2. Then run/re-run `composer install` this will make sure the Laratrust is installed in your project.
3. After installing it then `run composer dump-autoload` or `sudo composer dump-autoload` [for some of the Mac users]

4.Then `PHP artisan vendor:publish --tag="laratrust"`

You should be ready to go after that!

Answer (score 0):

add

**namespace Database\Seeders;**

at the top in  ( LaratrustSeeder.php ) file